# Wrong output with loop unroll under CUDA 6.5

Tags: cuda

I have the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define N_ITERATIONS 2048
#define UNROLL 32

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

/********************************************************/
/* KERNEL0 - NO INSTRUCTION LEVEL PARALLELISM (ILP = 0) */
/********************************************************/
__global__ void kernel0(int *d_a, int *d_b, int *d_c, unsigned int N) {

    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x ;

    if (tid < N) {

        int a = d_a[tid];
        int b = d_b[tid];
        int c = d_c[tid];

        #pragma unroll UNROLL
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < N_ITERATIONS; i++) {
            a = a * b + c;
        }

        d_a[tid] = a;
    }

}

/*****************************************************/
/* KERNEL1 - INSTRUCTION LEVEL PARALLELISM (ILP = 2) */
/*****************************************************/
__global__ void kernel1(int *d_a, int *d_b, int *d_c, unsigned int N) {

    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tid < N/2) {

        int a1 = d_a[tid];
        int b1 = d_b[tid];
        int c1 = d_c[tid];

        int a2 = d_a[tid+N/2];
        int b2 = d_b[tid+N/2];
        int c2 = d_c[tid+N/2];

        #pragma unroll UNROLL
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < N_ITERATIONS; i++) {
            a1 = a1 * b1 + c1;
            a2 = a2 * b2 + c2;
        }

        d_a[tid]        = a1;
        d_a[tid+N/2]    = a2;
    }

}

/*****************************************************/
/* KERNEL2 - INSTRUCTION LEVEL PARALLELISM (ILP = 4) */
/*****************************************************/
__global__ void kernel2(int *d_a, int *d_b, int *d_c, unsigned int N) {

    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tid < N/4) {

        int a1 = d_a[tid];
        int b1 = d_b[tid];
        int c1 = d_c[tid];

        int a2 = d_a[tid+N/4];
        int b2 = d_b[tid+N/4];
        int c2 = d_c[tid+N/4];

        int a3 = d_a[tid+N/2];
        int b3 = d_b[tid+N/2];
        int c3 = d_c[tid+N/2];

        int a4 = d_a[tid+3*N/4];
        int b4 = d_b[tid+3*N/4];
        int c4 = d_c[tid+3*N/4];

        #pragma unroll UNROLL
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < N_ITERATIONS; i++) {
            a1 = a1 * b1 + c1;
            //if (tid==0) printf("iteration %i %i\n",i,a1);
            a2 = a2 * b2 + c2;
            a3 = a3 * b3 + c3;
            a4 = a4 * b4 + c4;
        }
        //if (tid==0) printf("last iteration %i\n",a1);

        d_a[tid]        = a1;
        d_a[tid+N/4]    = a2;
        d_a[tid+N/2]    = a3;
        d_a[tid+3*N/4]  = a4;
    }

}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
void main() {

    const int N = 1024;

    int blockSize;      // The launch configurator returned block size 
    int minGridSize;    // The minimum grid size needed to achieve the maximum occupancy for a full device launch 

    int *h_a                = (int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));
    int *h_a_result_host    = (int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));
    int *h_a_result_device  = (int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));
    int *h_b                = (int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));
    int *h_c                = (int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        h_a[i] = 2;
        h_b[i] = 1;
        h_c[i] = 2;
        h_a_result_host[i] = h_a[i];
        for(unsigned int k = 0; k < N_ITERATIONS; k++) {
            h_a_result_host[i] = h_a_result_host[i] * h_b[i] + h_c[i];
        }
    }

    int *d_a; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a, N*sizeof(int)));
    int *d_b; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_b, N*sizeof(int)));
    int *d_c; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_c, N*sizeof(int)));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_b, h_b, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_c, h_c, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // --- Creating events for timing
    float time;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    /***********/
    /* KERNEL2 */
    /***********/
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    kernel2<<<1, N/4>>>(d_a, d_b, d_c, N);
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("GFlops = %f\n", (1.e-6)*(float)(N*N_ITERATIONS)/time);
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_a_result_device, d_a, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) if(h_a_result_device[i] != h_a_result_host[i]) { printf("Error at i=%i! Host = %i; Device = %i\n", i, h_a_result_host[i], h_a_result_device[i]); return; }

    cudaDeviceReset();

}
```

I'm compiling it using CUDA 6.5 for `compute_20, sm_21` (GT540M) and it works correctly for `UNROLL = 2, 4, 8, 16`, but it does not work anymore for `UNROLL = 32`, in the sense that the result is incorrect already for the first element of the output array.

The error message is:

```
Error at i=0! Host = 4098; Device = 4036
```

If I monitor the processing for `tid = 0`, i.e., I uncomment the `printf` lines, I see that `a1` holds the correct value until the last `for` iteration, while, immediately after exiting the `for` loop, the variable becomes incorrect. In other words, by uncommenting the two `printf`'s, the output is

```
....
iteration 2047 4098
last iteration 4036
```

which means that the `for` loop is executed correctly, but when exiting it, the value of the `a1` variable changes.

If I compile the code for `UNROLL = 32` with CUDA `5.5` and `6.0`, it works.

Having a look at the disassembled code, I see

**CUDA 5.5**

Very similar to CUDA `6.0` - not shown here

**CUDA 6.0**

```
            Function : _Z7kernel2PiS_S_j
    .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM21 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM21)"
    /*0000*/         MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];
    /*0008*/         NOP;
    /*0010*/         MOV R3, c[0x0][0x38];
    /*0018*/         S2R R0, SR_CTAID.X;
    /*0020*/         SHR.U32 R3, R3, 0x2;
    /*0028*/         S2R R2, SR_TID.X;
    /*0030*/         IMAD R15, R0, c[0x0][0x8], R2;
    /*0038*/         ISETP.GE.U32.AND P0, PT, R15, R3, PT;
    /*0040*/     @P0 EXIT;
    /*0048*/         MOV32I R17, 0x4;
    /*0050*/         IADD R7, R15, R3;
    /*0058*/         IMAD R8.CC, R15, R17, c[0x0][0x20];
    /*0060*/         IMAD.HI.X R9, R15, R17, c[0x0][0x24];
    /*0068*/         IMAD R20.CC, R15, R17, c[0x0][0x28];
    /*0070*/         LD.E R0, [R8];
    /*0078*/         IMAD.HI.X R21, R15, R17, c[0x0][0x2c];
    /*0080*/         IMAD R2.CC, R15, R17, c[0x0][0x30];
    /*0088*/         MOV R12, c[0x0][0x38];
    /*0090*/         IMAD.HI.X R3, R15, R17, c[0x0][0x34];
    /*0098*/         IMUL R13, R12, 0x3;
    /*00a0*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R10.CC, R7, R17, c[0x0][0x30];
    /*00a8*/         LD.E R14, [R2];
    /*00b0*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R11, R7, R17, c[0x0][0x34];
    /*00b8*/         LD.E R16, [R20];
    /*00c0*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R4.CC, R7, R17, c[0x0][0x20];
    /*00c8*/         SHR.U32 R3, R12, 0x1;
    /*00d0*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R5, R7, R17, c[0x0][0x24];
    /*00d8*/         IADD R20, R15, R3;
    /*00e0*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R6.CC, R7, R17, c[0x0][0x28];
    /*00e8*/         LD.E R18, [R4];
    /*00f0*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI R13, R13, c[0x10][0x0], R15;
    /*00f8*/         LD.E R21, [R10];
    /*0100*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R7, R7, R17, c[0x0][0x2c];
    /*0108*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R8.CC, R13, R17, c[0x0][0x28];
    /*0110*/         LD.E R19, [R6];
    /*0118*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R9, R13, R17, c[0x0][0x2c];
    /*0120*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R2.CC, R13, R17, c[0x0][0x20];
    /*0128*/         LD.E R9, [R8];
    /*0130*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R3, R13, R17, c[0x0][0x24];
    /*0138*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R4.CC, R20, R17, c[0x0][0x28];
    /*0140*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R5, R20, R17, c[0x0][0x2c];
    /*0148*/         LD.E R8, [R2];
    /*0150*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R6.CC, R20, R17, c[0x0][0x30];
    /*0158*/         LD.E R5, [R4];
    /*0160*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R7, R20, R17, c[0x0][0x34];
    /*0168*/         MOV32I R4, 0xfffff800;
    /*0170*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R12.CC, R13, R17, c[0x0][0x30];
    /*0178*/         LD.E R6, [R6];
    /*0180*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R13, R13, R17, c[0x0][0x34];
    /*0188*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R10.CC, R20, R17, c[0x0][0x20];
    /*0190*/         LD.E R13, [R12];
    /*0198*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R11, R20, R17, c[0x0][0x24];
    /*01a0*/         LD.E R17, [R10];
    /*01a8*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*01b0*/         IMAD R7, R18, R19, R21;
    /*01b8*/         IMAD R12, R17, R5, R6;
    /*01c0*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*01c8*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*01d0*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*01d8*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*01e0*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*01e8*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*01f0*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*01f8*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*0200*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*0208*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*0210*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*0218*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*0220*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*0228*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*0230*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*0238*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*0240*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*0248*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*0250*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*0258*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*0260*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*0268*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*0270*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*0278*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*0280*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*0288*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*0290*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*0298*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*02a0*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*02a8*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*02b0*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*02b8*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*02c0*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*02c8*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*02d0*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*02d8*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*02e0*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*02e8*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*02f0*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*02f8*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*0300*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*0308*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*0310*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*0318*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*0320*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*0328*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*0330*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*0338*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*0340*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*0348*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*0350*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*0358*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*0360*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*0368*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*0370*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*0378*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*0380*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*0388*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*0390*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*0398*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*03a0*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*03a8*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*03b0*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*03b8*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*03c0*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*03c8*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*03d0*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*03d8*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*03e0*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*03e8*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*03f0*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*03f8*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*0400*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*0408*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*0410*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*0418*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*0420*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*0428*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*0430*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*0438*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*0440*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*0448*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*0450*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*0458*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*0460*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*0468*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*0470*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*0478*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*0480*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*0488*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*0490*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*0498*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*04a0*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*04a8*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*04b0*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*04b8*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*04c0*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*04c8*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*04d0*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*04d8*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*04e0*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*04e8*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*04f0*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*04f8*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*0500*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*0508*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*0510*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*0518*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*0520*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*0528*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*0530*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*0538*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*0540*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*0548*/         IADD R4, R4, 0x20;
    /*0550*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*0558*/         IMAD R7, R7, R19, R21;
    /*0560*/         IMAD R12, R12, R5, R6;
    /*0568*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*0570*/         ISETP.NE.AND P0, PT, R4, RZ, PT;
    /*0578*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*0580*/         IMAD R18, R7, R19, R21;
    /*0588*/         IMAD R17, R12, R5, R6;
    /*0590*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*0598*/         IMAD R0, R0, R16, R14;
    /*05a0*/         IMAD R18, R18, R19, R21;
    /*05a8*/         IMAD R17, R17, R5, R6;
    /*05b0*/         IMAD R8, R8, R9, R13;
    /*05b8*/     @P0 BRA 0x1a8;
    /*05c0*/         MOV32I R4, 0x40000000;
    /*05c8*/         MOV32I R9, 0x4;
    /*05d0*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI R7, R4, c[0x0][0x38], R15;
    /*05d8*/         IMAD R4.CC, R15, R9, c[0x0][0x20];
    /*05e0*/         IMAD.HI.X R5, R15, R9, c[0x0][0x24];
    /*05e8*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R6.CC, R7, R9, c[0x0][0x20];
    /*05f0*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R7, R7, R9, c[0x0][0x24];
    /*05f8*/         ST.E [R4], R0;
    /*0600*/         ST.E [R6], R18;
    /*0608*/         ST.E [R10], R17;
    /*0610*/         ST.E [R2], R8;
    /*0618*/         EXIT;
```

**CUDA 6.5**

```
            Function : _Z7kernel2PiS_S_j
    .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM21 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM21)"
    /*0000*/         MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];
    /*0008*/         NOP;
    /*0010*/         MOV R3, c[0x0][0x38];
    /*0018*/         S2R R0, SR_CTAID.X;
    /*0020*/         SHR.U32 R3, R3, 0x2;
    /*0028*/         S2R R2, SR_TID.X;
    /*0030*/         IMAD R0, R0, c[0x0][0x8], R2;
    /*0038*/         ISETP.GE.U32.AND P0, PT, R0, R3, PT;
    /*0040*/     @P0 EXIT;
    /*0048*/         MOV32I R14, 0x4;
    /*0050*/         IADD R21, R0, R3;
    /*0058*/         IMAD R18.CC, R0, R14, c[0x0][0x20];
    /*0060*/         IMAD.HI.X R19, R0, R14, c[0x0][0x24];
    /*0068*/         IMAD R10.CC, R0, R14, c[0x0][0x28];
    /*0070*/         LD.E R15, [R18];
    /*0078*/         IMAD.HI.X R11, R0, R14, c[0x0][0x2c];
    /*0080*/         IMAD R12.CC, R0, R14, c[0x0][0x30];
    /*0088*/         MOV R22, c[0x0][0x38];
    /*0090*/         IMAD.HI.X R13, R0, R14, c[0x0][0x34];
    /*0098*/         IMUL R2, R22, 0x3;
    /*00a0*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R8.CC, R21, R14, c[0x0][0x20];
    /*00a8*/         LD.E R17, [R10];
    /*00b0*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R9, R21, R14, c[0x0][0x24];
    /*00b8*/         LD.E R20, [R12];
    /*00c0*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R4.CC, R21, R14, c[0x0][0x28];
    /*00c8*/         SHR.U32 R13, R22, 0x1;
    /*00d0*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI R16, R2, c[0x10][0x0], R0;
    /*00d8*/         LD.E R23, [R8];
    /*00e0*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R5, R21, R14, c[0x0][0x2c];
    /*00e8*/         IADD R19, R0, R13;
    /*00f0*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R2.CC, R16, R14, c[0x0][0x28];
    /*00f8*/         LD.E R22, [R4];
    /*0100*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R3, R16, R14, c[0x0][0x2c];
    /*0108*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R6.CC, R16, R14, c[0x0][0x20];
    /*0110*/         LD.E R2, [R2];
    /*0118*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R7, R16, R14, c[0x0][0x24];
    /*0120*/         MOV32I R3, 0xfffff800;
    /*0128*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R10.CC, R21, R14, c[0x0][0x30];
    /*0130*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R11, R21, R14, c[0x0][0x34];
    /*0138*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R12.CC, R16, R14, c[0x0][0x30];
    /*0140*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R13, R16, R14, c[0x0][0x34];
    /*0148*/         LD.E R10, [R10];
    /*0150*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R8.CC, R19, R14, c[0x0][0x28];
    /*0158*/         LD.E R16, [R6];
    /*0160*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R9, R19, R14, c[0x0][0x2c];
    /*0168*/         LD.E R12, [R12];
    /*0170*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R4.CC, R19, R14, c[0x0][0x30];
    /*0178*/         LD.E R8, [R8];
    /*0180*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R5, R19, R14, c[0x0][0x34];
    /*0188*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R18.CC, R19, R14, c[0x0][0x20];
    /*0190*/         LD.E R4, [R4];
    /*0198*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R19, R19, R14, c[0x0][0x24];
    /*01a0*/         LD.E R14, [R18];
    /*01a8*/         IMAD R5, R15, R17, R20;
    /*01b0*/         IMAD R9, R23, R22, R10;
    /*01b8*/         IMAD R11, R14, R8, R4;
    /*01c0*/         IMAD R13, R16, R2, R12;
    /*01c8*/         IMAD R15, R5, R17, R20;
    /*01d0*/         IMAD R21, R9, R22, R10;
    /*01d8*/         IMAD R14, R11, R8, R4;
    /*01e0*/         IMAD R16, R13, R2, R12;
    /*01e8*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*01f0*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*01f8*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*0200*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*0208*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*0210*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*0218*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*0220*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*0228*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*0230*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*0238*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*0240*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*0248*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*0250*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*0258*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*0260*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*0268*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*0270*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*0278*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*0280*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*0288*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*0290*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*0298*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*02a0*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*02a8*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*02b0*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*02b8*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*02c0*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*02c8*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*02d0*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*02d8*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*02e0*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*02e8*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*02f0*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*02f8*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*0300*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*0308*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*0310*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*0318*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*0320*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*0328*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*0330*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*0338*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*0340*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*0348*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*0350*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*0358*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*0360*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*0368*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*0370*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*0378*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*0380*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*0388*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*0390*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*0398*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*03a0*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*03a8*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*03b0*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*03b8*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*03c0*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*03c8*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*03d0*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*03d8*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*03e0*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*03e8*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*03f0*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*03f8*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*0400*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*0408*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*0410*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*0418*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*0420*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*0428*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*0430*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*0438*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*0440*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*0448*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*0450*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*0458*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*0460*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*0468*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*0470*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*0478*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*0480*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*0488*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*0490*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*0498*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*04a0*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*04a8*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*04b0*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*04b8*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*04c0*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*04c8*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*04d0*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*04d8*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*04e0*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*04e8*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*04f0*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*04f8*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*0500*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*0508*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*0510*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*0518*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*0520*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*0528*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*0530*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*0538*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*0540*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*0548*/         IADD R3, R3, 0x20;
    /*0550*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*0558*/         IMAD R21, R21, R22, R10;
    /*0560*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*0568*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*0570*/         ISETP.NE.AND P0, PT, R3, RZ, PT;
    /*0578*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*0580*/         IMAD R23, R21, R22, R10;
    /*0588*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*0590*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*0598*/         IMAD R15, R15, R17, R20;
    /*05a0*/         IMAD R23, R23, R22, R10;
    /*05a8*/         IMAD R14, R14, R8, R4;
    /*05b0*/         IMAD R16, R16, R2, R12;
    /*05b8*/     @P0 BRA 0x1a8;
    /*05c0*/         MOV32I R2, 0x40000000;
    /*05c8*/         MOV32I R8, 0x4;
    /*05d0*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI R4, R2, c[0x0][0x38], R0;
    /*05d8*/         IMAD R2.CC, R0, R8, c[0x0][0x20];
    /*05e0*/         IMAD.HI.X R3, R0, R8, c[0x0][0x24];
    /*05e8*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R14.CC, R4, R8, c[0x0][0x20];
    /*05f0*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R15, R4, R8, c[0x0][0x24];
    /*05f8*/         ST.E [R2], R5;
    /*0600*/         ST.E [R14], R9;
    /*0608*/         ST.E [R18], R11;
    /*0610*/         ST.E [R6], R13;
    /*0618*/         EXIT;
```

The `ST` operations for both CUDA `5.5` and `6.0` operate on `R10`, `R18`, `R17` and `R8` which are updated by the last `IMAD`'s, while for CUDA 6.5 they operate on `R5`, `R9`, `R11` and `R13` which are not updated by the last `IMAD`'s.

What I'm doing wrong?

My set up: core i7 laptop with Windows 7, compiling a release project, either `32`-bit or `64`-bit (same problem). The above refers to `64`-bit.

Command line:

```
# (Approximate command-line.  Settings inherited from host are not visible below.)
# (Please see the output window after a build for the full command-line)

# Driver API (NVCC Compilation Type is .cubin, .gpu, or .ptx)
set CUDAFE_FLAGS=--sdk_dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\"
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\bin\nvcc.exe" --use-local-env --cl-  version 2010 -ccbin "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"       --  keep --keep-dir x64\Release -maxrregcount=0 --ptxas-options=-v --machine 32 --compile -cudart static    -o x64\Release\%(Filename)%(Extension).obj "%(FullPath)"

# Runtime API (NVCC Compilation Type is hybrid object or .c file)
set CUDAFE_FLAGS=--sdk_dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\"
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\bin\nvcc.exe" --use-local-env --cl-  version 2010 -ccbin "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"       --  keep --keep-dir x64\Release -maxrregcount=0 --ptxas-options=-v --machine 32 --compile -cudart static        -Xcompiler "/EHsc  /nologo  /Zi    " -o x64\Release\%(Filename)%(Extension).obj "%(FullPath)"
```

**EDIT**

The problem only occurs when the two additional kernels are present. If I comment them out, everything works. The disassembled codes for the working and non-working cases are reported [here](http://pastebin.com/9ukPyZCe) and [here](http://pastebin.com/vWUR4cnS), respectively.

Comment: It appears you are compiling a release project, not debug.  Are you compiling for a 32-bit project (i.e. does `-m32` show up in the nvcc compile command?)  Using CUDA 6.5 RC on linux, the closest I come to your generated code is with `-m32`.   With CUDA 6.5 (not RC) on windows, and `-m32`, I come close to the SASS you display, but not identical.  I can't conveniently get to a CUDA 6.5 RC package for windows, my windows machines are already on CUDA 6.5 production release.  I assume your code should generate some kind of printout (on the last for-loop) if the error you're describing is detected?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks Robert, I have edited the question with more information. I'm now going to install the CUDA 6.5 production release version and see what happens.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I have installed CUDA `6.5` Production Release, but the problem persists. I have updated my question as well as the SASS codes and done experiments, not only for CUDA `6.0`, but also for CUDA `5.5`. For those two last cases, I have no issue at all.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue.  I have a laptop with Quadro1000M (cc2.1 just like your GPU) and win7.  I have VS2013 Express installed, as well as CUDA 6.5 Production Release.  I dropped your code as posted verbatim into the `vectorAdd` sample project.  The only change to project configuration I made was to change the code generation to `compute_20,sm_21`, and I built the Win32 release project.  The code runs without printout of any errors, just the `GFlops = 20.924648` output.  I've also tried CUDA 6.5 and 6.5RC on linux, both 32-bit and 64-bit with no luck there either.

Comment: It seems odd that your command line switches indicate `--machine 32` but the output is targetted to `x64\Release`.  Could you try dropping the code into the CUDA 6.5 `vectorAdd` sample project and building the Win32 release version of that, and see if you can reproduce the failure?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Robert, sorry, I agree that you cannot reproduce the problem with the code above. To minimize the size, I recklessly removed `kernel0` and `kernel1` from the reproducer as I thought they were unessential. I have added the two additional kernels I had in my original code. It seems that, without those kernels, everything works and the disassembled code is [this](http://pastebin.com/9ukPyZCe) and looks like reasonable. With the additional kernels, the code does not work and the disassembled code is [this](http://pastebin.com/vWUR4cnS) and seems not to be reasonable.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I have also dropped the code above into the  `vectorAdd` CUDA Sample project and, if I compile under the `release` mode instead of the `debug` one, I still experience the same issue.

Comment: Yes, I believe I can reproduce the issue now.  I have filed a bug (1552767) with nvidia, and will report back here if I learn or discover anything relevant.

Comment: The NV compiler team has reproduced the issue. In this case, it seems to require a very specific combination (multiple kernels, at least 2 of which have specific unroll instructions.)  So for this particular case, the workarounds should be obvious.  For general avoidance, my best suggestion would be to not issue specific unroll directives (let the compiler do it).  However, at the moment this doesn't seem like a likely or prevalent occurrence.  I expect this to be fixed in a future CUDA release, at which point I will update this question.  But I expect that will be some time in the future.

Comment: @RobertCrovella So is the `--machine` switch not relevant?  I'm a CUDA novice, but this setting seems fairly self explanatory, and evidently not set correctly for a 64-bit target.

Comment: I was only asking about `--machine` or `-m32` because I was having trouble reproducing the problem, so I was grasping at straws, and trying to scrub the info here for any possible difference compared to what I was doing.  I don't have any indication that this issue is specific to 32-bit or 64-bit apps.  I have tested and repro'd on 64-bit (linux) and the OP suggests repro on both 32-bit and 64-bit.  Whether or not OP has a proper build environment doesn't seem to be related to the issue in focus here.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Do you want to provide an answer? I would upvote and accept.

Comment: I usually wait until I have confirmed the fix in a publicly available release/release candidate.  I don't think I'll forget to come back to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have confirmed that the problem is fixed in CUDA 7 EA.  When CUDA 7 RC or CUDA 7 production release are available, the issue should be fixed there as well.